# Regex to Remove Everything After 4th Slash in URL

Tags: php, regex, substr, strpos

I'm working in PHP with friendly URL paths in the form of:

```
/2011/09/here-is-the-title
/2011/09/here-is-the-title/2
```

I need to standardize these URL paths to remove anything after the 4 slash including the slash itself. The value after the 4th slash is sometimes a number, but can also be any parameter.

Any thoughts on how I could do this? I imagine regex could handle it, but I'm terrible with it. I also thought a combination of `strpos` and `substr` might be able to handle it, but cannot quite figure it out.

Comment: Which implementation language are we talking about? The regex is not complicated, but the syntax for removing things using it depends on the language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function:

```
$parts  = explode('/', '/2011/09/here-is-the-title/2');
$output = implode('/', array_slice($parts, 0, 4));
```

Comment: Another great idea! Again...I wonder if this is faster than regex.

Comment: @Sardine: You could try to benchmark it yourself and find out :-) I would consider it highly probable that this is faster than regex.

Comment: @PlatinumAzure - That is on the todo list! I figured I'd ask in case anyone knew off hand. Thanks!

Comment: This appears to be the quickest method! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If your regex implementation support arbitrary length look-behind assertions you could replace

```
(?<=^[^/]*(/[^/]*){3})/.*$
```

with an empty string.
If it does not, you can replace

```
 ^([^/]*(?:/[^/]*){3})/.*$
```

with the contents of the first capturing group. A PHP example for the second one can be found at [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/MdCXz).

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
%^((/[^/]*){3}).*%g
```

with $1.

see http://regexr.com?2vlr8 for a live example

Answer (score 1):

you could also use a loop:

```
result="";
for char c in URL:
    if(c is a slash) count++;
    if(count<4) result=result+c;
    else break;
```